# Is it impossible to cast a string representation of a Page to a Page type?

Tags: c#, casting, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I've had this code in the OnLaunched() event of my App.xaml.cs "forever":

```
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            if ((roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageType")) &&
                (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageParam")))
            {
                rootFrame.Navigate((Type)roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"],
                                         roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageParam"]);
            }
        }
```

...but I guess it actually ran (execution state was terminated) for the first time, because I got this err msg:

*System.InvalidCastException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Type'.*

I'm assigning the current page to this roaming setting in every page's OnNavigatedTo() event:

```
App.roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"] = GetType().ToString();
```

Is the problem with my syntax, or is it my approach?

I suppose I could assign it this way instead:

```
App.roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"] = "DetailPage";
```

...and then have this in my OnLaunched() event:

```
if (roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"] == "DetailPage")
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(DetailPage), App.activeSection);
}
else if (. . . etc. . . .)
```

...but I'm attempting to be a little more "elegant" than that...I know I can step through it, but I wonder if there's a location I can look (in the Registry somewhere, I reckon) where the values saved for those roaming settings are viewable).

### UPDATE

After looking at this, and taking into account those pages that don't take an arg, I changed the code to:

```
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
        {
            if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageType"))
            {
                if (roamingSettings.Values.ContainsKey("CurrentPageParam"))
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate((Type)roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"],
                                             roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageParam"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate((Type) roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"];
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
rootFrame.Navigate(Type.GetType(roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageType"].ToString()),
                                roamingSettings.Values["CurrentPageParam"]);
```

Comment: Beware of what you serialize into CurrentPageParam, some simple types (for example TimeSpan) appears to be serializable but is incompatible with the Settings.Values dictionary serializer.